# Trying to find Firmware for Quanta DB15B-1U (S2B_3B20 and BMC version 3.79.00)

Tags: bios

We have a big problem with a Quanta D51B-1U server we had to buy so replace an old one that is part of a cluster and failed

We installed the server, but the cluster will not allow it to be added, because the firmware is older than the rest of the servers in the farm.

The server came with the S2B_3A17, BIOS Version, but we need it to be at version S2B_3B20 and BMC version 3.79.00. I've tried to find the CPU upgrade package at Quanta's webpage, but they only have one package available, and it is an older version

Does anybody have any idea on where can I get that CPU upgrade package? I haven't been able t find it anywhere